# Can someone explain this unit vector calculation for this circle inversion formula derivation?

Tags: vectors, circles, inversive-geometry

I'm really stuck.

I'm learning about circle inversion. More specifically, I was trying to understand how to derive the inversion formula for a circle, which seems to be explained here.

http://classes.yale.edu/fractals/circinvfrac/InvFormulas/InvFormulas2Mv.html#CircAnchor

[image: Inversion]

How is it that the unit vector is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2}}$?

Why is it not just $\sqrt{(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2}(a-c,b-d)$ itself?

It may sound like a really stupid question, but I've done quite a bit of Googling on "unit vectors", and nothing seemed to really explain this calculation.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks for helping me out with the editing @zoli :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2}}$ is the length of the vector between the two circle centers.

The vector itself is $(a-c,b-d)$. The unit vector, then, is the original vector divided by its length:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2}}(a-c,b-d).$$

Comment: Hi zoli, thanks for that.

Comment: I understood that it's the magnitude that has to be divided though

Comment: aaaaaah your edit made it a lot clearer. I've another question - since the magnitude is not a vector quantity, if we divide each of the entries i the vector by the magnitude, will it be of a value between 0 to 1?

Comment: By def: a unit vector pointing to the direction of a vector is the vector divided by its length. P.e. $\overline v=(1,1)$, its length is $\sqrt2$. the corresponding unit vector is $\frac1{\sqrt2}(1,1)$.

Comment: As illustrated by my litte example above.